# Strong laws and CLTs for sequences

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be iid RVs which are uniformly distributed over $\{A,B,C,D\}$. Let $R_n$ be the number of times that $ABC$ appears as a substring in $X_1 \cdots X_n$. It is easy to see that $\mathbb E(R_n) = (n-3+1)(\frac{1}{4})^3$, so $\mathbb E (R_n/n) = \frac{1}{4^3} = \mu$. I would like to prove a strong law, i.e. $R_n/n \rightarrow \mu$ a.s.

I was thinking to define RVs $\theta_n$ such that $\theta_n = 1$ if $ABC$ was the latest substring. Then the result follows by the SLLN if we can show that the $\theta_n$ are independent (since then $R_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i$. Is this the right approach? I can't seem to prove these are independent, since if $\theta_i = 1$, then $\theta_{i+1} = 0$.

EDIT: As mentioned in a comment, this approach doesn't work since the $\theta_i$ are not independent. However, something similar should work since they are almost independent. Only the previous 3 matter, i.e. $\theta_i$ and $\theta_{i-j}$ are independent for $j \geq 3$...

What about a central limit theorem? How can we find $\alpha > 0$ such that $\frac{R_n - \mu n}{\alpha \sqrt n} \rightarrow \mathcal N(0,1)$ in distribution?

Comment: If I understand you then clearly they are not independent: if a string ends ...ABCx then it cannot end ...yABC, which is what you are saying with $\theta_i=1 \implies \theta_{i+1}=0$.  Since the covariance is negative, you will find the distribution of $\frac1n \sum\limits_1^n\theta_i$ or perhaps $\frac1{n-2} \sum\limits_3^n\theta_i$ is closer to $\mu$ than it would be if they were independent

Comment: Yeah, so defining $\theta_n$ is not the right approach... Do you have any ideas for how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\theta_i$ and $\theta_{i+1}$ are not independent but $\theta_i$ and $\theta_{i+3}$ are. More generally, $\theta_{3i}$ are i.i.d. same goes for $\theta_{3i+1}$ and $\theta_{3i+2}$. Note that if $\theta_{3i} = 1$ then $\theta_{3i+1} = \theta_{3i+2} = 0$. Set up a sum, $R_n$, with these and se what happens with $R_n/n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

For the CLT note that each $\theta_{3i}$ is Bernoulli distributed.